# Send data primefaces to another page

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I´m newbie in primefaces, i have done a datatable and i show it in index.xhtml i have got a button when i push, it show the selection datatable (dialog) but i don´t know how to send the select datatable to another page. Sorry I´m learning english, thx.

**index.xhtml**

```
 <p:dataTable id="singleDT" var="emp" value="#{empresaBean.getEmpresaList()}" selectionMode="single"
    scrollable="true" scrollHeight="400" selection="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" rowKey="#{emp.CLAVE}"> 
        <f:facet name="header">
            Lista de Empresas
         </f:facet>

      <p:column headerText="Id">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.CLAVE}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="Nombre Empresa">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.NOMBRE}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="AÑO">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.EJERCICIO}" />
       </p:column>

<f:facet name="footer">
    <p:button outcome="/pages/menu/menuPrincipal.xhtml" value="Seleccionar" title="Ir Menu">
    </p:button>

<p:commandButton value="View" image="ui-icon ui-icon-search"  
        oncomplete="empresaDialog.show()"/>  
   </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="empresaDialog" resizable="false"  
              width="200" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold">  

        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  

            <h:outputText value="Clave:" />  
            <h:outputText value="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa.CLAVE}" />  

            <h:outputText value="Año:" />  
            <h:outputText value="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa.NOMBRE}" />  

            <h:outputText value="Año:" />  
            <h:outputText value="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa.EJERCICIO}" />  

        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:dialog>  



      </h:form>
   </h:body>
```

**EmpresaBean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="empresaBean")
@Scope
@Component
public class EmpresaBean {

    @Autowired
    private EmpresaService empresaService;
    private Empresa empresa;
    private Empresa selectedEmpresa;
    private List<Empresa> empresasSmall;

    public EmpresaService getEmpresaService() {
        return empresaService;
    }

    public Empresa getSelectedEmpresa() {
        return selectedEmpresa;
    }

    public void setSelectedEmpresa(Empresa selectedEmpresa) {
        this.selectedEmpresa = selectedEmpresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresaService(EmpresaService empresaService) {
        this.empresaService = empresaService;
    }

    public EmpresaBean(){
        empresa = new Empresa();
    //  empresasSmall=new ArrayList<Empresa>();
        // list.add(new Empresa(getEmpresaList());  
    } 
/*  
    public void addEmpresa(){
        empresaService.add(empresa);
        empresa = new Empresa();
    }  */

    public List<Empresa> getEmpresaList(){

        return empresaService.getAll();
    }

    public Empresa getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }
    public void setEmpresa(Empresa empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not send html to another page (dialog). You should push only data, which will be used on another page. 
To push data from datatable (which is considered to be a List) you should use @ManagedProperty annotation.

Assuming you have index page:

```
@ManagedBean(name="index")
@SessionScoped
public class IndexPage implements Serializable {

    private List<String> values;

    //getter and setter

}
```

and you have another page, where you would like to use that list:

```
@ManagedBean(name="nextPage")
@SessionScoped
public class AnotherPage implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{index.values}")
    private List<String> forwardedList; //list with values form index page

    //getter and setter

}
```

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/

**UPD**: if you would like to forward a row, but not a list, you should just make minor change in `AnotherPage` class:

```
@ManagedBean(name="nextPage")
@SessionScoped
public class AnotherPage implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value="{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}")
private Empresa selectedValue; //value from selected row in your table

//getter and setter
```

}

Comment: Ok, I understand you but how i know if i have choose a row or another row?

Comment: updates answer with solution for your case. Try that out

Comment: Ok, It´s works now, but i have other error, i write other question. :)